# Jquery mobile page seen much after the pageshow event on an android phone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a cordova/phonegap app using Jquery Mobile. My app feels very sluggish right now and I see that the main reason is that the page only shows up after about a second after I see the pageshow event being fired. Ideally, I expected it to be shown when the pageshow event is fired.

Also, during this meantime(after the pageshow before the page is actually shown) if I touch on the page at a certain point it fires the ontouch event on the item that is supposed to be present at that point. So the page is already there but maybe it's taking this time to render.

**Do you know how to make this page render faster using JQuery Mobile?** Is there something I can do with the custom Jquery Mobile builder that helps Jquery Mobile not do stuff that's not required?

Please note that I have turned off transitions globally on my app using

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

The mobile browsers has a delay of 300ms delay for touch events. To disable this you can use fastclick. It can remove that 300ms delay in your app.

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

This can help you too to make it work faster.

The browsers wait for 300ms to check if the user has done a single click or is going to do a double tab. If the user has not touched again before 300ms, its considered as a single touch click.. else it's considered as double tab.

Comment: Did my answer made sense?

Comment: Hi @Purus, thanks for the reply. but my question is different. I understand this 300ms delay and I am working around that. My issue is that the click has happened and the page has changed - the pagebeforeshow and the pageshow events on the new page have fired but I don't see the new page yet. It comes up some time after this. Also, I notice that this delay is lesser on better phones and more on slower older phones

Comment: Is DOM cache enabled? If so the pages are shown from cache making the page to look empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting another answer as I think this would be the solution for your updated question.

If my understanding of your problem is correct, disabling the DOM cache will solve it.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, domcache was enabled for some of the pages and I have removed that but it doesn't seem to help. The page still shows much after the pageshow event is fired.

Comment: I have disabled cache globally using the statement above and also removed every data-dom-cache="true" from my HTML. I don't think there is any cache present.